# In topology $X$ is also $Y$ means homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, equivalence-relations

E.g. $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is also the quotient space $S^n / (v \sim -v)$.  And when is it safe to refer to a space as one of it's homeomorphic spaces and perform further deductions from that homeomorphic space?

Comment: It is safe if you are only dealing with properties that are preserved by homeomorphisms. If you want to know if $X$ is complete, and $X\approx Y$, then it would not help to figure out completeness of $Y$, as completeness is not invariant under homeomorphisms.

Answer (score 3):

All of the topological information of a topological space is contained in its open sets, or equivalently, its closed sets.  What I mean by this is that any topological property is completely determined by the topology, ie, the open sets.

What is a topological property?  Well, at the risk of being tautological, it is exactly a property that is defined using only the notion of closed and open sets.  Since two homeomorphic spaces have exactly the same open and closed sets, they will also contain exactly the same topological properties.

Let's give a few examples of topological properties.

Examples:

1. Compact
2. Connected
3. Hausdorff
4. Separable
5. Normal
6. Discrete
7. Regular

Now, if the topological space has more structure, like a metric, then properties that depend on the metric, like completeness, are not topological properties, and therefore might not be preserved by a homeomorphism.  Notice that $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$, but the open interval is not complete, as $\mathbb{R}$ is.

So if you remain totally in the realm of topology, there is no danger in studying a space $X$ to learn about a space $Y$ if $X\cong Y$.

Comment: It can matter how natural the isomorphism is.

Comment: @zyx Naturality isn't really something you can talk about if you're just given two spaces.

Comment: @ThomasBelulovich, I don't think that's correct.  Particular definitions of naturality might not work, and even then, "two" spaces really tends to mean two elements from large families of equivalent objects.  There isn't one unique circle, for example, but a large collection of equivalent constructions with relations  between them.  But I agree there is a difference between "just two" spaces and a family, as explained in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

Plain isomorphism can be good enough if you study one object alone but this can fail in families (such as nontrivial bundles).  Natural isomorphism is almost always enough to treat isomorphic objects as equal.

This is assuming you are interested in isomorphism-invariant properties, and the notion of isomorphism is taken in whatever category accomodates the constructions to be done on $X$ and its isomorphs.